# How to install worker service in Linux machine

Tags: linux, systemd, virtualbox, services, .net

I have created a worker service using .Net Core. I have output `.dll` file. I want to install it on Gnu/Linux OS, that is Ubuntu Server running in *Oracle VirtualBox*.

I have dragged `.dll` file to Virtual machine and following [installing-a-net-core-service-on-linux-server](https://medium.com/@iqan/installing-a-net-core-service-on-linux-server-34abd5f4e9c2) article, but that is not clear enough.

Could anyone help me install service?

I have this configuration file.

```
[Unit]
Description=Dummy Service in .NET
# Requires=xyz.service
# After=xyz.service

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/user/iqan
ExecStart=dotnet DummyService/bin/debug/DummyService.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Hi Arvind, could you please provide `readlink -f DummyService.dll` or `realpath DummyService.dll` ?

Comment: @binarysta - How can I provide you? or you can try out with your random dlls too

Comment: if you have creared the `DummyService.dll` file, just go to the directory this file exist and run `readlink -f DummyService.dll` or `realpath DummyService.dll`.

Comment: @binarysta - I did but nothing happend. First do we need to create .service file of DumyService.dll?

Comment: could you please simple tell us where is this dll file you created? which directory?

Comment: This is there in download folder. From there itself I opened terminal by right clicking.

Comment: I just execute `readlink -f DummyService.dll` and other one without any prefix like `sudo`.

Comment: ok good! just while you are in download directory, execute `pwd`.

Comment: if I execute `pwd` nothing happens. Do I need to add something else before or after `pwd`?

Comment: what do you mean nothing happens? you will at least get error.

Comment: oh sorry.. It shows path `/home/linux/Downloads` but no error. If I do `sudo pwd` then asking password.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? Put it down and step away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change systemd service unit file to

```
[Unit]
Description=Dummy Service in .NET
# Requires=xyz.service
# After=xyz.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet  /home/linux/Downloads/DummyService.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

For start/stop/status the service

```
sudo systemctl start dummyservice.service
sudo systemctl stop dummyservice.service
sudo systemctl status dummyservice.service
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108332/discussion-on-answer-by-binarysta-how-to-install-worker-service-in-linux-machine).